# Nunit runs each test twice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, testing, nunit

I encounter a problem running my tests via NUnit. I dont know why but each test runs twice. The point is that on another laptop it normally runs only one time.

Have anyone the same problem and know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem.  In my case, I had both the [Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d) and the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/) of the NUnit Test Runner installed.  It seems they were both executing the tests, resulting in tests being run twice.

Uninstalling the Visual Studio extension solved the issue.

Comment: I've both Visual Studio Extension and the nuget packege. Removing the nuget packaget does'n solve my problem. I'll try the opposite.

Comment: If the above won't fix your issue, take also a look in your Control Panel, in **Programs and Features** and uninstall the Nunit installation from there.

Comment: For me, I uninstalled the nuget package and restarted VS.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where running the test with the Visual Studio NUnit3 runner, the test would run only once but when running in the command line with NUnit3-Command.exe, the test would run twice. I spent way too long chasing this down. I noticed that the command line runner was reporting 2 tests were run and came to the conclusion it was an issue in the dll. This may sound crazy but I copied all my test code into a new class, deleted the old, compiled and the test now runs just once in both scenarios.

Comment: This worked for me.  The project was .net v4.5 and was previously a MsTest project (with the MsTest icon in VS).  I trasferred the source code to a new v4.7 class library.  This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was having a base class and a derived class both having the TestFixture Attribute.  All tests from the derived class would run twice.

Fixed it by only putting attribute on base class.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference for others - I have run into same problem after installing Fine Code Coverage extension in Visual Studio Professional 2022, uninstalling it helped. I was using specflow + xunit.

Comment: Great shout, this was my issue. It turned out you can change a setting which resolves this: `Tools` > `Options` > `Fine Code Coverage` > `Run (Common)` > `RunMsCodeCoverage` > **`Yes`**.   

See [Why use MS Code Coverage](https://github.com/FortuneN/FineCodeCoverage/blob/master/README.md#why-use-ms-code-coverage-).

Answer (score 0):

The problem typically arises when you load a test container (.dll) multiple times.

This can happen if you load the test containers from a root floder that has both bin and obj folders inside, which is a typical setup of Visual Studio projects.

Try to limit your test container loading from the bin folders.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. And why on the other laptops it works proper but on this one not.

Comment: Did you look for the dll files inside the solution folders? You could also be building for two different configurations, such as bin\Release + bin\Debug

Answer (score 0):

The running of test can also be duplicated is when sequential tests accidentally have the same test parameters.

```
 [Test, Sequential]
            public void Integr_MController_DeleteGet_ReturnsViewAndModel(
 [Values("Do@london.com", "Do@london.com")] string firstEmail,


 [Values("Zyg@london.com", "Zyg@london.com")] HTTPstring updatedEmail) {test code}
```

Will run the same test twice and will show up in TestExplorer as the same test.

Answer (score 0):

In case you put the *.dll twice, the test get double executed.

Seen on NUnit.3.10.1, nunit3-console 3.9.0

Example:

`nunit3-console myTestDll.dll --test=MyNameSpace.Test myTestDll.dll** --result=myResult.xml`