# Spec Flow Test Cases Getting Called Twice

Tags: c#, specflow

We have written test case using Spec Flow,but when we run them,the test will get called twice?

Any idea,what might be the cause?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow. You should [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site work and to see how to ask questions which are likely to be answered. You need to provide more information than this. Ideally a [minimum, complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but at least show us an example of your code, tell us which test runner you are using, which version of specflow etc etc. Without this information your question is little more than 'My code is not working, what is the problem', and this type of question is very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're running these tests in Visual Studio and that you are using NUnit as the test execution framework for SpecFlow - I suspect you might have the NUnit test runner installed twice, which is causing the tests to run twice.

The NUnit test runner can be installed as both a Visual Studio extension, and as a NuGet package for your test project.  Make sure that you have only one of these installed.

See: [Nunit runs each test twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347281/nunit-runs-each-test-twice) for further reference.